# Django - Logged in User Not Populating in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I’m trying to create a form to when the current logged in user makes a submission the `user` column in `admin.py` gets populated with the logged in user.

My problem:
The `user` column gets populated when a new user gets created using the `CustomUserCreationForm` however when the newly created user makes a form submission with the form listed below, the `user` column doesn’t get populated.

The Custom User Model that I'm trying to get the username from is located in `from users.models import CustomUser` so I’m not sure why this isn’t working.

How do I get the current logged in user to populate in `admin.py` in the `users` column with the form listed below?

Any help i gladly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Code Below:

## user_profile/models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from users.models import CustomUser

class Listing (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

## user_profile/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from user_profile.forms import HomeForm
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

from user_profile.models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser


# Register models here.

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'created', 'updated', 'user']
    list_filter = ['name', 'zip_code', 'created', 'updated', 'user']

admin.site.register(Listing, UserProfileAdmin)
```

## user_profile/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import HomeForm
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


# add to your views

def change_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = HomeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile 
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

## user_profile/forms.py

```
import os

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.forms import widgets
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat

from avatar.conf import settings
from avatar.models import Avatar
from .models import Listing


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    created = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))    
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    address = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    zip_code = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Zipcode', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    mobile_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Credit Card', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_expiration = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Expiration Date', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    cc_cvv = forms.CharField(required=False, label='', max_length=100,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'CVV', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Comment: You have connected to post_save of CustomUser Model. That is the reason Listing entry is getting created when you create new user. Add a Signal on post save of Listing Model.

Comment: @NageshDhope I added `@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser, dispatch_uid="update_user")` and still no luck my friend. I've been trying multiple things. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NageshDhope I added `views.py` so you can check it out.

Comment: please add `forms.py` too.

Comment: @NageshDhope Just added. Thanks my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

forms.py

```
import os

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.forms import widgets
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat

from avatar.conf import settings
from avatar.models import Avatar
from .models import Listing


class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'cc_number', 'cc_number', 'cc_expiration', 'cc_cvv')
```

Add in models file

```
class ListingManager(models.Manager):
    def save_from_object(self, request, obj):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Add Update your Listing Model with `objects` as new manager

```
class Listing (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

    objects = ListingManager()
```

This should work, Also I am not sure about your idea of keeping user as OneToOneField (This will not allow having multiple records with same user instance), I think you need to change it to ForeignKey. Refer [What's the difference between django OneToOneField and ForeignKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and no luck. I'll play around with adding a foreign key and see what happens. If you have any other ideas troubleshooting please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: i added `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. then after a user submits i received an error in terminal that says `ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "Listing.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.` Any ideas?

Comment: Update `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. Also Login before submitting the form

Comment: `ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "Listing.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.` I still get that same error my friend.